# How to enable compression in asp.net Core 2.2 project for https site and avoid problems like CRIME and BREACH

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, https, compression, image-compression

I have a web application that is written using C# on the top of ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC framework.

My application displays lots of images on every request which makes load time high and increase bandwidth usage. To improve page load and bandwidth usage, I want to compress the HTTP response using [Brotli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brotli) and [Gzip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) formats.

Luckily Microsoft has a package that uses middleware to compress the HTTP response for me called [Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression/). From the package official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-3.0), compression for secured websites is disabled by default.

> Using compression with dynamically generated pages can lead to security problems such as the [CRIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRIME_(security_exploit)) and [BREACH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BREACH) attacks.

My question how can I compress the response while avoiding security issues?

Here is how I set up the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression/) package

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
    {
        options.Providers.Add<BrotliCompressionProvider>();
        options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
        options.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
        new[] { "image/svg+xml", "image/jpeg" });
        options.EnableForHttps = true;
    });

    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseResponseCompression();
    ...
}
```

The above setup will apply compression for the following MIMI types

- application/javascript
- application/json
- application/xml
- text/css
- text/html
- text/json
- text/plain
- text/xml
- image/svg+xml
- image/jpeg

Comment: There is technically no way. The mitigation of the exploits is on the client-side, and indeed some browsers (Chrome and Firefox, I think) have mitigations for these attacks. There's nothing you, on the server, can do, other than just flat out not allow compression at all, removing the attack vector.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I guess I am not clearly understanding the exploits. But, can I only compress image/jpeg MIMI type without falling into this issue?

Comment: Well, yes, but it would do you little good. JPEG is already a compressed format. It's like zipping a zip archive.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thank you. I am just trying to figure out if that exploit is limited to certain MIMI types. In other words, what if I compress everything except for `text/html` and `images`?

Comment: Not necessarily. The danger of exploit is secrets exposed in content. If the location of the secret in the document is a known quantity (a simple view source), then the response can be teased to expose the actual secret value, despite TLS encryption. If you don't have secrets or you aren't actually outputting them in HTML, JS, etc. then it's not a concern.

Comment: In truth, it's more a concern for things like banking institutions where your account number may be printed on the page, for example. CSRF tokens can also be a problem, though not in Core, as they're nonced. The problem isn't so much allowing compression on everything it could apply to, but rather in the one-off cases where you actually might end up doing something where you shouldn't allow compression.

Comment: Again thanks alot for explaining. I am a bit confused on what you really mean by secrets? I mean in what condition would one put a secrent into an html?

Comment: A secret is generally anything that shouldn't be exposed past the user authorized to see it. It could be an account number for a bank account as I already gave as an example or even just high-value PII: email, address, phone, etc.

Comment: That is perfect example. To be on the safe side, what if I compress only my public pages? In other words, anything requres authentication, I would not compress. Any request at `Account/*` pages or `Admin/*` I would not compress.

Answer (score -1):

In addition, you may also "compress" image prior to sending over, for example, using :

```
    private byte[] CompressImageToQuality(System.Drawing.Image image, int quality)
    {
            EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, quality); 
            ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");
            EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
            encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;
            using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                image.Save(stream, jpegCodec, encoderParams);
                return stream.ToArray();
            }
    }
```